# Block bad bot based on a query param signature

Tags: nginx, botnet

My `nginx` instance is getting hammered every couple of days by some bad bot using random query parameter values.

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log:209.107.204.224 - - [14/Mar/2023:16:01:42 +0100] "GET /?ttrp353217=ttrp540516 HTTP/1.1" 501 560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"
```

When it hits, it quickly causes resource starvation, and eventually HTTP 501/504 for regular customers.

The `ttrp` query param name/value always contains a random number.

Is this some well-known bot?

Is there a way to configure `nginx` to block requests containing specific query param regex? AFAIK, I can block the request if the query param exists, not if query param *starting with prefix* exists...

I blocked the address for the time being, but that one is likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

Use fail2ban that parses logs and blocks matching addresses for the set period.

The other option is to use Cloudflare, which does this, and much more, automatically, for free.

I’d say hosting anything publicly without Cloudflare is a bad idea in 2023.

Disclaimer: no, I’m not affiliated with, or endorsed by CF. But I’ve been using their services for free for years, and my server has never been brought down, ever.

Comment: Cloudflare's free plan doesn't really stop DDOS attacks though. However, their Authenticated Origin feature is free, but you have to setup in Nginx, and that can prevent any requests sent to your server that don't pass through Cloudflare, which helps a lot.

Comment: Care to explain why the free plan doesn't "really" stop DDoS?

Comment: Ref: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-pro-vs-free-ddos-protection/378671

Comment: That link doesn't really say what you claimed. It says better insights and more advanced firewall options that may make mitigation _easier_ for _advanced users_. And the free user says one time he had to implement stuff in the application layer because CF was not enough for that - in no way did he imply Pro would have been better at this.

Comment: I think it's fairly well-known among Cloudflare users, the free plan details are rather vague which has led to regular frustration, for example: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/ddos-protection-do-not-block-flooders/400039

Comment: "Fairly well-known" is not an argument. It is not known by me, and I've been using CF for free for years without issues. The post you linked also even explicitly mentions the 22 requests per second being the "issue", which is a minuscule amount for CF to block. Of course, you can set your own rate limits on your end, which should be trivial. Or just use under attack mode. The link you provided even links to a CF article, and OP even says it resolved their issue. You keep coming up with random links, and yet they keep refuting your claims lol

Comment: You can be pedantic if you like, but I'm posting this for other users that come across this page, the free plan does not protect against most DDOS attacks. You can manually setup WAF rules, yes, but most users don't know that. There is no automated detection or analytics of DDOS attacks that helps free users easily stop attacks. I'm posting this for future visitors, I'm not interested in debating you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a WAF (Web Application Firewall). Cloudflare is a solution as mentioned by previous answers. But I personally use [Naxsi](https://github.com/nbs-system/naxsi) to prevent these attacks.

You can integrate Naxsi with Fail2Ban and UFW to block bad IPs automatically.

[Naxsi can be installed as a dynamic module for nginx](https://vpsfix.com/8652/install-naxsi-web-application-firewall-for-nginx-and-virtualmin/).